# Защита от xss в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xss, xss-атака

Прочитал, что в Laravel защита от xss реализована автоматически используя синтаксис двойной привязки `({{$value}})` либо эскейпинг (это одно и то же получается)? Можете объяснить простыми словами, что это вообще значит? И от каких ещё атак Laravel защищает по умолчанию?